# Where Did the Protocols Go

Tags: xcode, protocols, beta

In the new Xcode 6 beta, I attempted to make an Objective-C `protocol`. To my dismay, when I clicked Create New File, the `protocol` template we all knew and loved from previous Xcodes was gone. 
[image]

I thoroughly scoured the entire Create File menu to no avail. Does anyone know where the `protocol` template can be found, or will I have to make one from scratch with an empty `.h` file?

Thankyou for your time.

Comment: I upgraded this question - I don't see why anyone downgraded it because it is a legitimate question. I think it is stupid for XCode to remove the protocol template and force us to copy in the lines Khanh gives below - if they are going to offer a template for a .h file and put C/C++ lines of code in that template that we then have to overwrite, there is no reason to not have a protocol template. Is it a huge deal? No. Is it annoying? yes.

Comment: @Marc Thankyou, Sir. The disappearance of the Protocols is very concerning.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Add a new file . Source Heading -> Select "Objective C Empty File" -> Click Next.
then give the protocol name -> in the dropdown list select Protocol option -> click Next button 
   -> select the place you want to create protocol file -> click Create Button

Comment: This creates a .m file. Do we not want a .h for a protocol ?

Answer (score 0):

It's gone. Make a new .h file and paste this in

```
@protocol MyProtocol <NSObject>

@end
```